# underscore.js with node-express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, underscore.js

I am trying to use underscore.js in a HTML file hosted with node-express server. This file is being used to render the dynamic data on client side. Below are the codes:

in app.js:

```
var cons = require('consolidate');
app.engine('html', cons.underscore);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.locals._ = require("underscore");
```

in HTML:

```
var template = _.template($('#client-list-template').html(), {clients: response});
```

here "response" is a JSON

in same HTML under template script

```html
<script id ="client-list-template", type='text/template'>
        <table class="table striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th><th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% _.each(clients, function(client) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= client.clientID %></td>
                        <td><a class="btn">Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <% }); %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>
```

running this code throws and error:

> `ReferenceError: clients is not defined`

Can someone please help me understanding what is the error and how to resolve it. Same HTML when hosted in Apache server works fine.

Comment: have you logged `response`? it looks like it may be undefined

Comment: `_.template` doesn't take two arguments. It takes one (the template) and returns a function, which itself takes one argument (the data).

Comment: @Jack It does actually [take two arguments](http://underscorejs.org/#template), but the second is not the data, it's the settings for the template string. But yeah, Vinny, you should do what he says.

Comment: Well, are you passing `clients` into the template as data?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it this way?

```
var template = _.template($('#client-list-template').html());
$('.output-div').html(template({
     clients : response
});
```

Also how are you getting the response variable?